# Problem regarding binding ObservableCollection to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

today I've been struggling with proper binding and it seems like i can't figure out what is wrong with my approach. I have one basic window with ListView as it's main component. When I try to bind ListView's ItemSource to the ObservableCollection<> through XML, it seems like it doesn't work, but if I change the property through C# code, it works just fine. My guess would be it has something to do with visibility of the ObservableCollection<>, but whenever i try to make it public i get error that base class is less visible than the other class. Could anyone explain what am I missing here?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<dataModel> items;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            items = new ObservableCollection<dataModel>();
            
            
            InitializeComponent();
            populateData();

            //LV1.ItemsSource = items; <= works with this uncommented
        }
```

and XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="LV1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="264" Margin="55,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="552" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="title" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding title}"></GridViewColumn>
                    
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

dataModel.cs:

```
public class dataModel
    {
        public string title { get; set;}
        public bool isDone {get;set;}

      
    }
```

Comment: You need public properties to bind.  It's also not clear that you've set your datacontext.

Comment: Also. If you only have one thing to show then you can use a listbox rather than listview. Listview is used for multi column data. Listview is a sort of a lighter weight datagrid.  Way back in the day, there was no datagrid in the wpf toolbox. They just had listview.  That is a bit low on functionality so they added the datagrid.

Comment: @Andy - No, i don't seem to set datacontext as it wasn't really shown anywhere i looked (MSDN guides and many answers on stack). Though adding it just above the commented ItemsSource (DataContext = this;) it still doesn't show anything.
 As for the data - i have public class with 2 public fields (one string and one bool), that's why i went with listview.

Comment: Ike I said. Fields still won't bind. You still need a public property to bind.

Comment: I've updated the question with dataModel.cs.
I really appreciate the help you're providing, but Im kind of lost at "you still need a public property to bind". Both observableCollection<dataModel> items and the model itself are public. What do you mean by public property?

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured out the difference and made it work now - thanks for your explaination, I've learned a lot thanks to you.